# can I use both 'unsafe-inline' and 'unsafe-eval' in the same script-scr or do I need to add a new script-scr?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, content-security-policy, gatsby-plugin

I am working with the [gatsby-plugin-csp](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-csp/) and want to understand if it is possible to add two keywords both 'unsafe-inline' and 'unsafe-eval' in the same script-scr and make them work? Or do I need to create two different script-scr? There are a few sources that I must use and some them of need eval() and others inline scripts.

Can I do this?

```
// In your gatsby-config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-csp`,
      options: {
        disableOnDev: true,
        reportOnly: false, // Changes header to Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only for csp testing purposes
        mergeScriptHashes: true, // you can disable scripts sha256 hashes
        mergeStyleHashes: true, // you can disable styles sha256 hashes
        mergeDefaultDirectives: true,
        directives: {
          "script-src": "'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' www.example.com",
          "style-src": "'self' 'unsafe-inline'",
          "img-src": "'self' data: www.google-analytics.com"
          // you can add your directives or override defaults
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

Or should I do this?

```
// In your gatsby-config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-csp`,
      options: {
        disableOnDev: true,
        reportOnly: false, // Changes header to Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only for csp testing purposes
        mergeScriptHashes: true, // you can disable scripts sha256 hashes
        mergeStyleHashes: true, // you can disable styles sha256 hashes
        mergeDefaultDirectives: true,
        directives: {
          "script-src": "'self' 'unsafe-inline' www.example.com",
          "script-src": "'self' 'unsafe-eval' www.example.com",
          "style-src": "'self' 'unsafe-inline'",
          "img-src": "'self' data: www.google-analytics.com"
          // you can add your directives or override defaults
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

I have tried using the first option with both 'unsafe-inline' and 'unsafe-eval' in this case half of them give errors like `Refused to load the script 'http://embed.example.com/next/embed.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'`

I also get this error `Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://www.google-analytics.com https://www.googletagmanager.com`

When I change the order of the keywords putting 'unsafe-eval' then 'unsafe-inline' I still get errors refusing to run other scripts.

Comment: The second definitely will not work as only one unique object key can exist.

Comment: @code what about the first one?

Comment: Sorry, not sure. I don't work with Gatsby.

Answer (score 0):

You could have two CSPs defined, but not the same directive twice in one policy. If you define multiple policies, your content still needs to pass all policies, adding another one can only make it stricter.

Your first script-src is "'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' www.example.com", which allows anything from the same server (same host, same port and same or safer scheme), inline scripts, eval (new Function(), setInterval(), setTimeout() and eval()) and scripts from [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

Your first error is caused by script from embed.example.com, which is blocked by your policy which only allows 'self' and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). You can add embed.example.com or replace [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) with *.example.com.

The second error is likely related to inline event attributes (like onclick, onload etc), click on the link in the error message to see the violating code. You generally need to rewrite them using event handlers. You might be able to allow them with additional efforts in CSP level 3, but I don't think there is full browser compatibility yet.

Comment: thank you and how would I define two CSPs using that plugin?

Comment: Why would you want two CSPs? It is likely not a solution to your problem and only something I would do in certain special and advanced cases.